# how to include a 3rd column in the result table of a COUNT and group by procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following select statement which works fine

```
SELECT status_id, COUNT(status_id) As total
FROM tbl_project INNER JOIN lkp_status
ON tbl_project.status_id = lkp_status.record_id
GROUP BY status_id
```

I would like to include the status_name field in the result table but this is not allowed:

```
SELECT **status_name**, status_id, COUNT(status_id) As total
FROM tbl_project INNER JOIN lkp_status
ON tbl_project.status_id = lkp_status.record_id
GROUP BY status_id
```

"because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

But I just want to have a third column indicating the name of the status_id for each count, which may not be unique :S

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You can't add STATUS_NAME to the GROUP BY?

Comment: what table has the column `status_name`?, since in your examples you changed the tables from `lkp_status` to `lkp_project_status`

Comment: Is your PK of status really called `record_id`? Why not just `status_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  tp.status_name,
        a.status_id,
        a.total

FROM (  SELECT status_id, COUNT(status_id) As total
        FROM tbl_project INNER JOIN lkp_project_status
        ON tbl_project.status_id = lkp_project_status.record_id
        GROUP BY status_id) A

INNER JOIN tbl_project tp
ON a.status_id = tp.status_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ad `status_name` to the `GROUP BY`, otherwise it won't let you include it on your `SELECT`. So, assuming that `status_name` belongs to the `lkp_status` table, your query should be:

```
SELECT s.status_name, p.status_id, COUNT(status_id) As total
FROM tbl_project p
INNER JOIN lkp_status s
ON p.status_id = s.record_id
GROUP BY s.status_name, p.status_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  status_id,
        status_name = (SELECT status_name FROM tbl_project Where status_id = tp.status_id)
        COUNT(status_id) As total
  FROM  tbl_project tp INNER JOIN lkp_status ON tp.status_id = lkp_status.record_id
GROUP BY status_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query actually works, you should be able to just add the name to both the SELECT clause and to the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT status_id, status_name, COUNT(status_id) As total
FROM tbl_project 
INNER JOIN lkp_status ON tbl_project.status_id = lkp_status.record_id
GROUP BY status_id, status_name
```

This *might* give you surprising results if status names aren't unique.